# How to forward declare functions in a Lua module?

Tags: lua, editor

I have a Lua module written in C compiled as a shared library, but when I use the module, editors cannot autocomplete it because they cannot see the content of the library.

In C, editors can deduce from the header files, how do you do that in Lua?

The Lua standard library does that but I can't figure out how. Every lua editor can tell me about standard library functions (their signature and documentation). How does it get this info from? How do I add such documentation to my own lua module?

Comment: "*How does it get this info from?*" The editors probably hard-coded them (that is, they have some file(s) containing available stuff and they have a Lua standard library file already written). Lua's standard library isn't that big, after all. It is certainly not parsing a C header.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on editor you use. Each editor has own implementation, and you must check documentation how to extend autocomplete.

For **notepad++** documentation about autocomplete:
https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/auto-completion/,
and file for this: `Notepad++\autoCompletion\lua.xml`